# Sending an array from masterview to detailview in a splitviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uisplitviewcontroller, send

How can i send an array from the masterViewController to the DetailViewController in a splitviewController?

edit
i have buttons in my masterview, when you select buttons the title of those buttons are "saved" in the array. when you click the "ok" button the strings that are "saved" in the array need to be showed in the detailview(i'm using a label). So i want the array to be "send" to the detailview.

I'm sure it is very basic, i'm new to objective c and i'm just testing how you can make the communication work between the master and detail view.

Comment: What does "sending an array" means? How do you use these controllers, what is the object hierarchy between them? Show use some code, tell us what did you try and what does not work.

Comment: i have buttons in my masterview, when you select buttons the title of those buttons are "saved" in the array. when you click the "ok" button the strings that are "saved" in the array need to be printed in the detailview. So i want the array to be "send" to the detailview.

I'm sure it is very basic, i'm new to objective c and i'm just testing how you can make the communication work between the master and detail view.

i thought i was clear enough, my mistake. :D

Comment: do you have access to the "master view" from your "detail view"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically pass the data to the detail view controller when you have initialized it from the master view. Add an array type property to the detail view controller and pass your array right after you created it (or requested from the segue if you are using storyboards). Then you can configure your detail view based on the passed data that it will be ready when the view is loaded.